# Can you view the XML generated by .NET when using a JavaWS service?

Tags: c#, java, xml, asp.net-2.0, java-ws

How can I view the XML being sent to a Java Web Service from a C#-based ASP.NET page?

I've created a disco object web ref in .NET from my Java WSDL, but when I use the likes of Fiddler to view the XML attached to the HTTP request, instead I see the form parameters being passed. Is there a way I can view the serialized XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tcpmon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/), from Apache, which can intercept traffic and redirect it to another host/port.

You set up a listener on port A, and all traffic is forwarded to host/port B.

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I was looking for. For some reason the HTTP watchers I've been using don't pick up the .Net XML. However, sending the info here first shows it up a charm. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you can view at the HTTP request and response with a packet sniffer like Ethereal/Wireshark.

Comment: Yeah, that's what Fiddler does but no dice I'm afraid. Just the infamous VIEWSTATE and the other form parameters but no XML.

Comment: If you don't see XML, then your web service call is not marshalling correctly. In a correctly formulated request, you can see the XML.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a play around with the parameters and see if I can get it to output the XML.

Comment: It seems that XML is being generated after all but just not being displayed by Fiddler. I'll take a look into the two you mentioned above though in case they're better. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You see the XML in the request header, along with any other request parameters, cookies, etc ....

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the XmlSerializer and serialize the object instance you are about to pass, to the disk, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. I am certain this is not the best way to do it, but i guess it will work. The idea is to inject a respone filter and overide the write method to log all the output generated from the ASP.NET page.
To see how to program an ASP.NET filter check this article :

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/468_Protecting_Email_Addresses_Using_Response_Filters.aspx